# Why can’t we drop “The reason” and just say “Why she is still single is because...”?

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, relative-adverbs

I know a relative adverb "why" can be followed by a clause and make the clause a noun phrase. It can play a role as an object or a subject in another sentence.

For example)

> I know the reason why she is still single.

Sometimes, the antecedent is okay to be dropped, if readers can guess there has to be the antecedent "the reason" with the context.

> I know (the reason) why she is still single.

Likewise, the under-written sentence is possible.

> The reason why she is still single is because she is ugly.

However no native speaker says like this:

> (The reason) Why she is still single is because she is ugly.

Wrong???
Why? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: We might say "Why she is single is a mystery" but not usually the inversion you are asking about.

Comment: @WeatherVane Would a native speaker ever say something like “Why he’s still confused is because no-one explained it well.”? I think we would drop the “why” as well “the reason”, “He’s still confused because...”

Comment: @ColleenV - Yes, a native speaker would say that. It puts more emphasis on the reason than simply saying "He's still confused because...". Personally, I prefer "The reason [why] he is still confused is _that_ no-one has explained it well."

Comment: @KateBunting But why? I don’t think this question is about “What’s the best way?” but rather about if there is a reason why it’s OK to drop this part but not that part.

Comment: @ColleenV - I can imagine, in answer to the comment "I wonder why she's still single", some unkind person replying "Why she is still single is because she's ugly" - but I  consider it to be poor English.

Comment: @KateBunting I don’t know. I think the unkind person would probably say “She's ugly, that’s why.” It’s times like these I wish I had a more formal grounding in linguistics.

Comment: @KateBunting: I see nothing wrong with *Why she is still single is because she's ugly*. Warming to my theme, [***Why you think that is beyond me**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Why+you+think+that+is+beyond+me%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So, *Why she is single is her ugliness*? The because seems to be my sticking point.

Comment: @ColleenV: Well, that's a somewhat different usage. Strictly speaking, I'd say a "why- clause* is a kind of ***noun*** (in contexts where it's completely interchangeable with ***the reason why...*** - also a noun phrase). And the normal syntax is ***The reason IS** [some statement*, a "tensed" clause]*. Where that "statement" is often preceded by the word ***because***. But usage is obviously changing a lot in this area right now - witness people saying things like *She's single **because ugly***, and *Irregular verbs are hard to learn **because English***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So what about *Why you think that is because you were educated by wolves.*  is it grammatical, but not idiomatic?  I feel like the because is making “why” and “is” redundant. *You think that because...* or *Why he thinks that is likely due to his upbringing...*

Comment: Subordinate "why" clauses are either relative clauses functioning as reason adjuncts ("That's the main reason [why she got so angry]"), or interrogatives (embedded questions) as in "I know [why he did it]", where the meaning is "I know the answer to the question 'Why did he do it?'"

Comment: @BillJ I interpret that last one as “I know the reason why” not as “I know the answer to a question starting with “why”.  Do you think “the reason why” a set phrase, or are there other similar constructions? I can’t think of any.

Comment: @ColleenV In your interpretation, "I know why he did it" would have to be analysed as a 'fused' relative construction, but that won't work because "why" doesn't occur in 'fused' relatives, only in interrogatives and 'regular' integrated relatives.

Comment: @ColleenV:  I might struggle with the *semantics* of *Why you think that is because you were educated by wolves,* but syntactically / idiomatically it doesn't bother me. It's just that the explicitly "subject + verb" format of ***Why** [statement] **is** because [reason]* (where *[reason]* is a secondary statement "explaining" the main one) is an unnecessarily verbose alternative to plain *[statement] because [reason]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Okay What about `(The reason) Why she is still single is due to her personality`.

Comment: @ColleenV My main question is about Why she still single is improper, when it takes a subject in the clause while omitting the antecedent - The reason -. Anyway, I didn't expect using "because" in the main clause to cause an argument among you guys.

Comment: But now I got it and I realized why you are talking about "because". According to Practical English Usage, `567. Reason In an informal style, why/that is often left out. 
The reason she doesn't like me is that I make her nervous.
『Some people consider it incorrect to use a because-clause as a complement after
reason (as in Sorry I'm late - the reason is because I overslept).』`

Comment: @KateBunting As well, I've got to know certain condition to allow the reason to be omitted. `the place where ..the day when ..the reason why ... 『The place, the day or the reason can be dropped in an informal style, especially in the middle of a sentence.... 
Spain's where we're going this year.
Why I'm here is to talk about my plans. (More formal: The reason why I'm here is...)』`

Comment: I don't think the difference between ***Why I'm here is to talk about my plans*** and ***The reason why I'm here is...*** is anything to do with formal/informal. It's just that the former is even more "clumsy" than the latter. Neither formal nor informal, *normal* phrasing would simply be ***I'm here to talk about my plans*** (there's no good reason to include either "reason" or "why" in that context).

Comment: @Tae-Bbong-E I think your question is very interesting, especially because I don’t have a good answer :) I am bringing up other things in the comments to see if maybe that might inspire someone to write a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a mistake in your reasoning with this sentence:

> > I know (the reason) why she is still single.

That is not actually the sentence here that is being shortened. Nothing is being shortned. Compare:

I know why...
I know what...
I know who...
I know where...
I know which...

In none of these examples would we be thinking "I know (the thing) what ..."
"I know the place where..."

In each of these 'why', 'what', 'who' are acting as pronouns all by themselves. Native English speakers could ask, for example, "Did you ever get 'the why'?" meaning "Did he ever tell you why this is happening/going to happen?"

Comment: Hi. I have seen the possible cases to drop (the reason, the place, the time) regarding relative adverbs in Practical English Usage and other  learning materials.